# Problema con regex url

Tags: regex

tengo el siguiente problema.

No se me da nada bien regex y me gustaría saber si me podríais echar una mano en crear el siguiente regex con la siguiente estructura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debe comenzar con `http` o `https`. Después con `://`. Despues con una url en formato texto o numérico. Seguido de `/texto` o n veces `/texto/` y finalizar con `texto`.

El texto puede ser numérico, texto, alfanumérico, con guiones o cualquier caracter.

Aquí os dejo un par de ejemplos de urls:

http://axisqgissrv.aguasdevalencia.es/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe

http://195.77.18.238/arcgis/services/tm_medio_ambiente/calidad_ambiental/MapServer/WmsServer

https://carto.icv.gva.es/arcgis/services/tm_medio_ambiente/calidad_ambiental/MapServer/WmsServer

Comment: COmo sugerencia, siempre puedes añadir lo que hayas intentado y los errores que encuentras al usarlo. Preguntar sin incluir muestras de haberlo intentado siempre será mal visto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hice una expresión regular que puede que te sea util.

Ejemplo de expresión regular:

```
/^(http|https)+:\/\/+[a-z0-9.]+\/(.*)/
```

Explicación:

- `^(http|https)` -> El texto tiene que comienzar por http o https
- `+:\/\/+` -> El texto debe que contener ://
- `[a-z0-9.]` -> Permite letras minusculas, numeros y el simbolo punto "."
- `+\/(.*)` -> El texto debe contener / y a partir del slash puede contener cualquier texto

(Como no sé que lenguaje estas utilizando, el ejemplo está en javascript)
Ejemplo JS:

```
let texto = "http://195.77.18.238/arcgis/services/tm_medio_ambiente/calidad_ambiental/MapServer/WmsServer";

const regex = /^(http|https)+:\/\/+[a-z0-9.]+\/(.*)/;

if (regex.test(texto)) {
  console.log("coincide, todo bien");
} else {
  console.log("no coincide.");
}
```